# Compare user's time zone with the website's office location time zone

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, time

I am working on a project where i need to SHOW the visitor of the website a message in the contacts area like:

Contact no: +91-99-3241-5285 `[You can call us now]`

The message is highlighted in the above line, now my question is, how to compare the user's time zone with the working hours of the company's office.

**P.S. - Suppose the company is in INDIA, and its working hours are 9.00am to 5.00pm.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you need the user's time zone to determine if it's currently between  the hours of 9a-5p somewhere in India?

Comment: Why do you need to do the calculation on the user's machine? If you do it on the server, you only have one time zone to worry about. Besides, the user may be running happily with the timezone set wrong, which means the browser will calculate the wrong time for your timezone.

Comment: I am a bit idiot in geography. That why i cant decide how many time zones are needed. So what is the probable solution?

Comment: You only need to know the current time at the office location to know if it's within the working hours there.  Doesn't matter where the user is geographically. If the web server is running in local time for the office, you don't need to convert at all.  If the web server is using UTC or in another time zone, you just need to get current time and convert it using the office's time zone.  Do this in PHP, not Javascript.

Comment: Basically, LHMathies is right. The best solution would be to check the time on the server side, using php / asp.net or whatsoever. Only if you have a static website you should do it on the client side with javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript to determine the users timezone offset:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

```
var d = new Date()
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
document.write("The local time zone is: GMT " + gmtHours);
```

Then calculate e.g. the current time in INDIA (GMT + 5:30 if i'm not wrong) and show "you can call us now" if the resulting time is within the working hours.

```
var diff = gmtHours - 5.5; // -> difference between users timezone and india in hours
var indiaDate = new Date();
indiaDate.setTime(d.getTime() - (diff * 60 * 60 * 1000));
document.write("<br />Current time in India: " + indiaDate.toString());
```

See the working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/RLsw9/

Answer (score 1):

The replies immediately below your question are correct.  There should be no need to know the client's time zone to calculate whether or not the current time is within hours of operation.  It doesn't really matter whether it's currently 8:00am US Pacific, 11:00am US Eastern, or 11:00pm in Manila, Philippines.  The important thing is what time it is relative to the business hours, not relative to the client.

Typically on all web servers I run, I set the server time to UTC.  When people enter their hours, either have them enter it in GMT or, if you want them to be able to enter the hours in their local time, have a time zone list or combo box on the page.  You can use PHP's [DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) function to help.

So, for example, say someone enters that their hours are from 9:00am to 5:00pm in the Asia/Calcutta time zone.  When you're using the time for calculations, do something like this, assuming you have rows named something like `hrs_start`, `hrs_end`, and `hrs_tz`:

```
$hrs_tz = new DateTimeZone($row['hrs_tz']);
$hrs_start = new DateTime($row['hrs_start'], $hrs_tz);
$hrs_end = new DateTime($row['hrs_end'], $hrs_tz);
```

Now you can use these hours to calculate whether or not the hours are in or out of their business hours.