# GMT Time to Real Time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a project where I need to be able to get GMT time using Jquery and post it into a MYSQL DB through PHP. Then I need to get the local time factor of the user and save it into the db. After that using JS/JQuery convert GMT to the users local time. I was hoping someone could give me a code example if possible. I really appreciate you time, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the user manualy select their timezone, one approach is to use the javascript date object to collect infomration about the users local time, and use it in a subsequent request

```
var timestamp = new Date();
document.getElementById('timestamp_target').value = timestamp.getTimezoneOffset();
```

I'm in Australia at +10 GMT, and the value returned by getTimezoneOffset is -600 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a starting point:

[Compare user's time zone with the website's office location time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178951/compare-users-time-zone-with-the-websites-office-location-time-zone)

Followed by the use of AJAX to post the data to a php script, which inserts it into the database. A quick Google search will tell you this.