# compare user time zone (anywhere in the world) to current Pacific+one hour in PHP

Tags: php, validation, datetime

This project includes creating a form for users to enter the start and end time of a promotion.  The site where the promotion will be live operates in the Pacific Time Zone and the user creating the promotion could be anywhere in the world.

The start time must be one hour greater than the current PST (or PDT depending on season).  The current method of validating the start time is not working because it pulls the local time of the user's computer.

I need a way to compare the user's local time to Pacific Time and validate that the promotional start time is one hour greater.

My working theory is to find the offset between the user's local time and GMT time, then find the offset between current Pacific time and GMT (which varies by 7 or 8 hours depending on DST--right?), then apply these offsets to the user's time and compare to Pacific time plus one hour.

I have succeeded in finding the necessary offsets and alerting the correct current time in Pacific time in various strings and timestamps but the overall logic escapes me.  Also, I have been unable to successfully add one hour to a TimeStamp.

this question is similar, and many others, but in this case the OP has a fixed offset:
[Compare user's time zone with the website's office location time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178951/4174712)

Current code:

```
function valid() {
var starttime=$('#1-PromotionalSaleStartTime').val();
var endtime=$('#1-PromotionalSaleEndTime').val();
    var now = new Date();
    var hour= now.getHours();
    var min = now.getMinutes()+10;
    var nows= parseInt(hour)+1;
    var time=nows+':'+min;     
    var presentime = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()
    var month =now.getMonth()+1;
    var day = now.getDate();
    var output = (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +(day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/'  + now.getFullYear() + ' '+time;
    var now    = (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +(day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/'  + now.getFullYear() + ' '+presentime;
    var present    = new Date(now);
    var oneDay     = 24*60*60*1000;    // hours*min*sec*milliseconds
    var firstDate  = new Date(starttime);        
    var secondDate = new Date(endtime);
    var diffDays   = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    var diff       = Math.round(Math.abs(( present.getTime() - firstDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    var presentTimeStamp = +'<?php echo time(); ?>' * 1000;
    var firstDateTimeStamp = Date.parse($('#1-PromotionalSaleStartTime').val());

var err        = 0;


<?php if($this->add!="" && isset($this->add)) {?>

if(presentTimeStamp > firstDateTimeStamp) {
$('#1-PromotionalSaleStartTime').after('<ul class="errors"><li>Sorry, but you cannot add past date.</li></ul>');
        err++;
```

}

```
<?php } ?>
    if(diffDays==0){
             $('#1-PromotionalSaleEndTime').after('<ul class="errors"><li>The date difference between Start and End dates should be 24 hours.</li></ul>');
    err++;
     }

    if(starttime < output){
              $('#1-PromotionalSaleStartTime').after('<ul class="errors"><li>Your Start time should be at least 1 hour more than the current Pacific Time like. '+ output +'</li></ul>');
    err++;
}

if((Date.parse(starttime)> Date.parse(endtime)) ){
    $('#1-PromotionalSaleEndTime').after('<ul class="errors"><li>End Time cannot be less than Start Time plus 1 day.</li></ul>');
    err++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the Server side:

```
/* timetest.php */
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dateInfo'])){
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); $data = array();
  $dt = new DateTime;
  $pacificPlusOneOffset = dt->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->getOffset();
  $data['diff'] = +$_POST['dateInfo']-$pacificPlusOneOffset;
  echo json_encode($data);
}
else{
  // could be some kind of hack
}
?>
```

AJAX should send JavaScript on the Client side, like:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
// more code to run other code here
function post(url, send, success){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'), ec = [], s;
  for(var i in send){
    ec.push(encodeURIComponent(i)+'='+encodeURIComponent(send[i]));
  }
  s = ec.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+'); x.open('POST', url);  
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-length', s.length);
  x.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200 && success){
      success(eval('('+x.responseText+')'));
    }
  }
  x.send(s);
}
post('timetest.php', {dateInfo:new Date().getTimezoneOffset()}, function(result){
  console.log(result.diff);
})
}
```